# Create a html window within another html window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I currently have a page with a few buttons. When I click on the button I want to open a new html page within the parent page. I want to do this in such a way that the parent window becomes transparent and the new page is over it. How can I go about doing this? I have tried to use Iframes but it does not give me the output that I want.

Comment: Use window.open() or window.showModalDialog are the built in ways. I personally prefer to use jquery.ui dialog because it is not subject to popup killers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James Kirsch has given you one way to do it.  Another is to have a hidden DIV that you show when you need it.  In both cases, you may have to place a semi-transparent GIF image behind the DIV (or opened window) so someone can not do anything with the rest of the web page until they have finished interacting with the new window.  You can do this by using the z-index CSS command.  So the DIV would be:

```
<DIV style='z-index:100;'>....</DIV>
```

and the image would be something like

```
<img src="PUT YOUR PATH HERE" style='position:absolute;top:0%;left:0%;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:50;'>
```

This would put the GIF image halfway between the web page and the DIV.

The above is what is happening when you go to a website and they grey out everything behind the new window.  It also keeps people from pushing on buttons when you don't want them to do so.

IFRAME stands for something like INSERTED_FRAME where the "INSERTED" part means it is inserted into your pre-existing web page.  That is why it doesn't work.  Neither will the FRAME command work because (again) it is embedded into the pre-existing web page.  You are wanting to lay the new window on top of the web page.  Thus, Mr. Kirsch' answer and my own.  Note that you can also use a TABLE command to do the same thing - even if it is frowned upon to use tables presently.  It is the STYLE part of the command that causes the HTML element to appear above the rest of the web page and not any particular HTML command itself.  Also, the "position:absolute" part of the STYLE command is what overrides the web page's positioning of the element.  Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

In the Javascript have you considered using the following?

```
window.open();
```

This call appears to take parameters for Position and Size, you may be able to close the previous window also if you desire, or manipulate it.

Example:

```
window.open('this.html','','left=15,top=15,width=800,height=600');
```

Reference: [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/javascript-dynamic-document-creation-in-new-windows.html)